# how to read the excel file table starting from the row color and compare with the 2nd file with the same format

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, openpyxl

I have a excel file like this [image: Table]
Have to read the table under the row in red and store in df and read the next table starts from red and store in another df similarly for next table alone with the same of row in red.
How to find the first row in red which may start from row 10 or 20 or column A or B or C and store in DF accordingly
Appreciate your help in advance

Tried openpyxl but unable to store the data in 3 different df for 3 different table

Comment: You should include any code you've already tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to identify the cell color is red or not first

```
def is_red_color(cell):
    return cell.fill.start_color.rgb== 'FFFF0000'
sheet=workbook.active
cell_color = sheet['B302']

if is_red_color(cell_color):
    print("Cell is read")
else:
    print("not red")
```